# Caching the axios httpService in NestJS

Tags: caching, axios, nestjs

Within our application we use the Axios HttpService to do some request to a third-party api.
Because the amount of data returned bij de api is so huge, we would like to cache the responses.
In the docs is wasn't able to find some examples of how to do this. 
I'm currently doing this as follows:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    CacheModule.register({
      ttl: 15,
      store: redisStore,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I register the CacheModule globally.
Then import it in the module where i need it.

In the service where i use the third-party api, i create an interceptor where i go and cache the reponses. Very crude and just for testing.

```
constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService,
              private readonly cache: CacheStore) {
    httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      cache.set(response.request.url, response.data);
      return response;
    }, error => Promise.reject(error));
  }
```

First of all this doesn't run, because the CACHE_MANAGER can't be imported into the CacheModule, for some reason. 
Second this is a more a Node.js way of creating such interceptors and not the NestJS way.
But is this a way to move forward or is there a more effecient way and if yes, what way is that?

Answer (score 7):

The [CacheModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching) is not the right tool here, as it means to cache **ingoing** requests (the requests your service receive, so it doesn't proceed them again and send back a cache result).

What you're trying to do is caching the **outgoing** requests (the one your service makes to 3rd-party services). For mysterious reasons, I couldn't find it documented in NestJS documentation either, but here's how you can go:

---

As you're using Axios, you can implement caching using the [axios-cache-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter) npm package.

```
npm install --save axios-cache-adapter
```

Then you need to create an adapter (preferably in the constructor of your service, see notes below):

```
const cache = setupCache({
  maxAge: 3600 * 1000, // 60 minutes
});
```

and provide this adapter as part of the AxiosRequestConfig alongside your request:

```
const config = {
  adapter: this.cache.adapter,
};
this.httpService.get( url, config );
```

You should be good with some caching now!

**IMPORTANT NOTES:**

- caching should be used, and will likely work, only on GET requests
- use the *setupCache* function **only once** (in the constructor of your service for instance); if you create one cache object for every request, this cache will be empty everytime, defeating the purpose of it